# Scheme streams of matrices

Tags: scheme, sicp, r5rs

I would like to have a stream in scheme that holds a bunch of matrices that have a certain order.

The stream-car of this stream would be the matrix [1 6 0 3]; that is, row 1 col 1 is 1, row 1 col 2 is 6, row 2 col 1 is 0, and row 2 col 2 is 3.  Each matrix is technically a list, but I have a representation (constructor and selectors) for a 2x2 matrix.  So, this will be a stream of 2x2 matrices.

Now, the next item in the stream should be  [2 10 0 5].  The pattern here is that the matrices in the next stream increases by the following: [k (4k+2) 0 (2k+1)] where k is the kth matrix.

I have an idea how I want to store these.  As an example, I know that I can get a continuous stream of ones with:

```
(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

and a continuous stream of integers with:

```
(define integers (cons-stream 1 (add-streams ones integers)))
```

So, I would like a continuous stream of matrices that are in the format described above.  That is, the first one (the car-stream) will be a matrix represented by [1 6 0 3] then a matrix represented by [2 10 0 5] then a matrix represented by [3 14 0 7].

So, I know it will be something like:

```
(define start-matrix '(1 6 0 3))

(define init-stream (cons-stream start-matrix 
                             (add-streams ___________
                                          init-stream)))
```

The underlined is what "I think" is the missing piece.  I've removed the "add-streams" procedure from this post to clear my post up.

***EDIT:  Realized I think my "start-matrix" has to be 1 6 0 3, not 1 4 0 2.

But there has to be a way to add 1 4 0 2 to the kth matrix.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Which part of the above are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi itsbruce.  Thanks for reading this.  I just want a stream of matrices that are in the format described.  That is [1 6 0 3] then [2 10 0 5] then [3 14 0 7].  it continuously makes a stream of matrices with this pattern.  The actual pattern is [k (4k+2) 0 (2k+1)]  I cleaned up my post a bit by removing the definitions for "add-streams" and the mapping procedure.  It should be evident what I want without them.

Comment: Yes, you want an infinite stream.  What part of creating that don't you know how to do?  Or do you just want people to write all the code you haven't written yet?

Comment: No, not at all.  I said "I know it should be something like..." above.  I'm missing a key piece.  Trust me, I've spent hours trying to figure this out and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Yes, but since your answer is missing everything about your thoughts apart from the basic spec, how can anybody else know which key piece you are missing?  It's like saying "I want to build a car" and not explaining whether it's the wheels or the engine that defeats you.

Comment: If you have no idea how to define **add-streams**, say so.

Comment: I'm sorry Bruce... I went back and re-read it and I'm having a hard time figuring out what else I need to say.  I need a stream of 2x2 matrices, each in list form, where each matrix deep you go, that matrix changes by the formula [k (4k+2) 0 (2k+1)] where k is the kth matrix.  I thought maybe saying how I can construct a stream of ones and ints may be helpful to being able to do this since I know what I have is pretty close (in my post).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18033/discussion-between-matt-and-itsbruce)

Comment: OK, edit makes it a bit more clear.  So it's what goes in _______ that you want help with?  Now I understand.  And if I didn't have to run out the door to get to work, I'd write a proper reply now ;)

Comment: After all this, Matt, I hope this did you some good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, firstly, you realise you're going to have to define your own version of **add-streams** to do the matrix addition?  (I realise this may have been in what you edited away).

Secondly, can you not see what is missing between the SICP example and your version?  In the SICP example, there is a function which provides a constant stream of 1s.  1 is what is added to each new element of the **integers** stream.  Now, there's something you want to add to each new member of the **init-stream** stream.  Surely you can work out what that is?  I mean, if you add it ever time and you do it k times... (you mention it so many times, you must know what it is).   So all you are missing is a function that delivers an endless stream of that one thing.

Thirdly, do you realise why the SICP example adds new elements from the **ones** stream, rather than just adding 1 each time?  (There's a principle being demonstrated).

Fourthly, do you see that **init-stream** is not a good name for this function?  **init-stream** indicates a general purpose function, whereas you are defining something that returns a very specific stream.  Why not just follow the SICP naming examples and name it for what it returns?

My third and fourth questions needn't be answered for you to solve your problem; I'm just interested to know if you grasp the point.

Comment: Hey thanks Bruce, these are good tips.  Yes, I got it working!  I did have to use the add-streams method like you say, just modified.  So I wrote an add-2x2 which does basic matrix addition and used the SICP stream-map with that procedure.  I also had to reconstruct the stream like you mention "thirdly", to produce a constant stream of the matrix to be continuously added.  Saw your post earlier but only had access to stack via my phone.  Wanted to write you a thanks for your help.